# [Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.11.0)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

I tried to upgrade my parse version to my code, yet the result is so annoying.
I've already download the new SDK from parse.com website. and replace the old one, and its still doesn't work.
So i decided to delete all framework and re-add all of that, and the result still doesn't work.

Here is my code that cause the error :

```
>  let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        currentInstallation.addUniqueObject("adirax", forKey: "channels")
        currentInstallation.saveInBackground()
        let subscribedChannels = PFInstallation.currentInstallation().channels
```

and :

```
>  // MARK: Push Notifications
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()

        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("adirax") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            if succeeded {
                print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
            } else {
                print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the error :

> 2015-12-28 22:31:38.205 Adira Calendar[538:151876] [Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.11.0)

I've read other similar post but different parse version, but that doesn't help me to solve this problem.

**ADD INFO**

When i try to build the application it run successful, but when i try to run on my phone suddenly the error showed up. (Description Error above)

**SOLVED**

```
Not sure if this really worth to try but it works. even though it's so annoying. 
I have to create a new workspace and start all over the project ( can use copy paste some file ). And i have to re-create all the certificate i have already before. 
But at least this works, 
If anyone know how to solve this problem fast, please tell me too.
Thanks!
```

Comment: @adolfosrs is there any solve in this case ? or i have to recreate whole project from the start ?